# PHP Zend Framework - How to Get Request URI Fragment from Request Object?

Tags: php, zend-framework, request, uri

Say e.g. i have a URI `http://127.0.0.1/somecontroller/someaction#12345` that takes me to the `someAction()` action of the someController controller. From there, i am able to retrieve the Request object via `$this->getRequest()`.

i am also able to retrieve various information regarding the URI from the Request object.

But, how can i retrieve the fragment (i.e. the "12345" part after the # in the e.g.)? Neither `getRequestUri()` nor `getParams()` turn up the fragment part.

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity what was your use case?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The fragment part of the URL is never sent to the server via GET requests (or any kind of HTTP request for that matter), the only way you can get it is if you write a Javascript snippet that parses the URL and sends the fragment back to the server via Ajax for instance.

This can't be done with PHP alone.

Answer (score 3):

According to HTTP protocol specification, the fragment part is ignored. However, browsers do support redirects with hash.

If you generate hashes automatically, you may pass the `id` as the request parameter:
`http://127.0.0.1/somecontroller/someaction/id/12345/#12345`

and then:

`$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')`

But this will hot handle the case with the hash only, e.g. when user enters the URL manually.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use:

```
explode("#",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

because when you call `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, you never get the word after `#`. For example your link `www.example.com/about#test`, and when you call `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, you just get `www.example.com/about`.

Comment: `explode`, according to the PHP manual itself: *Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.*

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the php function(s) `explode("#",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?`  Maybe I've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Alix Axel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89771/alix-axel), but there is a way, although very dirty and ugly, this can be done, IF, and only IF, you are calling it from a web browser.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['token'])) {
      die(var_dump($_GET['token']));
  }
?>

<form id="teste" action="?" method="get"><input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value=""></form>

<script>
    document.querySelector('#token').value = window.location.hash;
    document.querySelector('#teste').submit();
</script>
```