# How to make hashtag links?

Tags: php, url, hashtag

How to make for example `www.example.com#test` ?

I know how to use switches for `www.example.com?test=1`

But I really need `www.example.com#test`

Is there possibility to use `$_GET` function to make it do something?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/php-get-value-from-url-after-sign/2317518#2317518) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-htmllink-970328

```
"URLs can also be used to name locations within HTML documents using the fragment     identifier syntax, e.g.

 See: <a href="#s3.2">section 3.2</a> for details.
      ...
  <a name="s3.2">Section 3.2</a>The Bigger Picture"
```

Comment: I didn't mean this. On some websites there's possibility to use #links to show/execute previously hidden/unexecuted text(or div)/code.

Comment: The # information is never sent to the server. So you could not get it do anything with php. You could probably get it to do something with Javascript (and AJAX and therefore trigger PHP).

Comment: Using page fragments to control the view state is a sign that they are using a client side MVVC framework.