# Getting Url Parameter In php After # From Address Bar Url

Tags: php

```
http://xxxx.us/a/6126/securitycheckzpsfc10cc9.jpg#id=558554
```

I want to Get Url Parameter After Hash.

```
$hash = $_GET['hash'];
```

Not Working

I want to Get Url From Address Bar.
And Get the Part After Hash.

```
<?php
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$url1 = parse_url($url);
echo $url1['fragment'];
?>
```

This Is Also Not Working.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would think that either of your attempts would actually work.

Comment: the parameter after hash is not sent to the server, its a browser anchor

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/php-get-value-from-url-after-sign

Comment: you could bind a click event to your anchors and create a GET parameter

Comment: or you could url encode the hash symbol: `%23`, it will only work as part of another parameter after the `?` though

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript [location.hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp), you can change the hash to a `GET` parameter and send it to your PHP script

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://example.com/?some_parameter=x" class="hashed_link">Link</a>

<script>
    $().ready(function(){
        // navigate to in page anchor for testing
        window.location.href="#hash=12345678";

        // bind anchor click event
        $('.hashed_link').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            hash_anchor = $(this).attr('href')+'&'+location.hash.substr(1);

            alert(hash_anchor);
            //window.location.href=$(this).attr('href')+location.hash;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But then you'd have to refresh the page.

Comment: Didn't you get `index out of bounds exception` with your user name? :P

Comment: Chuck Norris has no bounds - pass your request to him and he will take care of it

Answer (score 0):

The hash isn't passed to the server, it is client-side only.

What you are trying to do is not possible, however, it would be possible to get the full URL via Javascript.

You should look into better ways of doing what you want to do. Why don't you pass it as a GET value instead?