# how to get the url of current opened page with #tag in php

Tags: php, url, uri

I want to get the url of the currently opened page. I am basically interested in the #part of the url.
My url is like this
/jmeercat/public/manageMyclan#autoreload
and
/jmeercat/public/manageMyclan#

I want to know whether the opened page is # or #autoreload?

How to get this in php

Comment: You can't parse that on server side .. in other words it won't reach the server-side script at all.

Comment: Did you try anything??

Comment: Yes I tried this-<?php echo "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?> but it is giving only url not the part after #

Comment: You can't get the fragment(part after hashtag) through PHP. You will have to use JavaScript to get the current fragment and then send it through AJAX.

Comment: @Adherence but that is again a problem. I am loading some content of the page based on this fragment but the javascript is executed after the page load.

Comment: You [can't get the hastag part from the url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2317523/2329962). This simply isn't send to the server.

Comment: Then I suggest you just use GET variables.

Comment: duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url