# get the value from URL using number sign #

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Hello if I have an href with `#test=10`, how can I get that value using codeigniter?

Example: I have `www.example.com/tester#test=10`

Is it possible to get the value of `test`?

Comment: console.log(window.location.hash)

Comment: see post [PHP - get value from URL after # sign][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/php-get-value-from-url-after-sign

Comment: By default codeigniter restrict url special characters like #.

Comment: So if I add a # in my href that link isn't actually sent to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using php

```
$url=parse_url("http://domain.com/#test=10 ");
echo $url["fragment"];
```

if url fregment test=10 then use `explode()`

```
$e = explode('=', $url["fragment"]);
echo $e[1];
```

or using javascript

```
alert(window.location.hash); and split it
```

For more :- [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/php-get-value-from-url-after-sign)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think php can get that value alone.
`$_SERVER['query_string']` or similare skip the hash.

- You can use window.location.hash in javascript and then send it to php (various way).
- Use apache to create an environment variable that contain the hash
- Use apache to rewrite hash into url for php to get it