# How to redirect to a page using PHP in one page website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have one a page webiste www.yahavi.com (all pages in 1 html) in which different pages are referenced using their div id (eg; #home, #contact ). After successful sign up I want to direct user to my thankyou page with id #thanku . How can i do that using my PHP script that runs after form submission.

```
home url: www.yahavi.com/#home
form at : www.yahavi.com/#contact
thankyou: www.yahavi.com/#thanku
```

I am using   header (Location: /#thanku) in my PHP but this doesnt work.

Note: I dont want a complete new html page to reload.

Comment: is necessary use hashtag for routing?

Comment: how does your script work for changing the display currently?

Comment: You would probably want to do the redirect in javascript. I would assume most stuff is loaded through ajax so have php send back a "redirectTo" property that JS looks for and if set does a location.href.

Comment: use hashtag in js not in php.. look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/php-get-value-from-url-after-sign

Comment: make sure you specify the file name header("location: http://www.yahavi.com/home.html#thanku")

Comment: @unixmiah the file name is probably an index file, so it is unnecessary to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript on your PHP code like this:

```
<?php

<script> location.href="#thanku" </script>

?>
```

Try that. I hope this helps.

UPDATE

If you do AJAX instead, it would be best. After signup, if the user signups successfully, on the javascript file you can use location.href="#thanku".

For that, you would need to do an AJAX request in your signup form.

Comment: This is an error..You certainly cant do it like `<?php <script>location.href="#thanku" </script> ?>`.. Instead it can be done like  `<?php echo "<script>location.href='#thanku'"; </script> ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just PHP. No need for JavaScript or jQuery.

Declare a global variable for storing your base path like this

```
$BASE_URL="www.yahavi.com/";
```

and redirect to the specified page like

```
header("Location:'".$BASE_URL."#thanku'");
```

Comment: How is that any different than what is being done now? Either redirecting to "`/#thanku`" or "`http://yahavi.com/#thanku`" should be the same, shouldn't it? Also you're missing the protocol, so it wouldn't work as expected anyway.