# Change class of body according to the url in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

Here is my url

For Login - `http://localhost/ang/#/login`

For Dashboard - `http://localhost/ang/#/dashboard`

Here is my html for body tag

If this is current url is `http://localhost/ang/#/login` then the body should have the `class="login-layout"`  tag i.e.,

```
<body ng-cloak="" class="login-layout>
```

else it should have

```
<body ng-cloak="" class="no-skin">
```

I tried to take do this in php by i can't take the url after `#` [like said here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2317508/4044949)

**Is this possible to do in AngularJS itself ?**

**Update :**

I tried to do this in AngularJS

From the controller i can get the url after `#`

```
var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
```

but how can i change the class name..

Comment: Do you consider using ng-class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to do this in a project and this is how I achieved it:

inside my main app controller I have:

```
// Inject the $location service in your controller
// so it is available to be used and assigned to $scope
.controller('AppCtrl', ["$scope", "$location",...

    // this_route() will be the variable you can use
    // inside angular templates to retrieve the classname
    // use it like class="{{this_route}}-layout"
    // this will give you -> e.g. class="dashboard-layout"
    $scope.this_route = function(){
         return $location.path().replace('/', '');
    };
```

Which exposes the current route name on the scope.

then my body tag simply reads this like:

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="{{this_route()}}-view" ng-cloak>
```

You can similarly use this with $state and read the `$state.current.url` and assing it to scope

Comment: Can you pls elaborate a little pls, bcoz i am beginner in it

Comment: Thanks, i will try it

Comment: Also I suggest you forget about the no-skin class as in css you can only assign stuff to the login-layout and they wont appear for elements no in the login layout. that much simpler than adding more logic to handle the one you don't want to have skin for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89457/discussion-between-anto-and-xgreen).

Answer (score 2):

this is how i would do

```
<body class="{{currentclass}}" ng-cloak>
```

now in login controller just do

```
$rootScope.currentclass = "login-layout";
```

and in every other controller just do

```
$rootScope.currentclass = "no-skin";
```

**OR**

in app.run just check for the  login path.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location){
rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current){
    if ($location.path() == '/login') {
          $rootScope.currentclass = "login-layout";
    }
    else{
          $rootScope.currentclass = "no-skin";
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey your answer is very good, but i do have a problem in it.. can you solve it pls

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like in my example below

```
<body ng-cloak="" ng-class="bodyClass" class="login-layout>

$scope.bodyClass = "mainClass"
var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
if (..) {
   $scope.bodyClass = "sometAnotherMainClass";
}
```

Shoud controller should look like this

```
angular.module('youAppName').controller('yourController', [ "$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.bodyClass = "mainClass"
    var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
    if (..) {
       $scope.bodyClass = "sometAnotherMainClass";
    }
    }]);
```

Comment: I am getting this error ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Comment: Look, my approach is for controllers - it means that you need to write this code in each controller.If you want to do this functionality once - just create mainController, and put this functionality there

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most "Angular" way to solve it is using a directive. The biggest benefit is that you don't have to set a scope variable in every controller you use.

This is how it would look:

```
app.directive('classByLocation', ['$location', function($location) {
  var link = function(scope, element) {
    scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
      if ($location.path() == '/login') {
        element.removeClass('no-skin').addClass('login');
      }
      else{
        element.removeClass('login').addClass('no-skin');
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: link
  };
}]);
```

And in your HTML:

```
<body class-by-location>
```

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zT5l6x9KYOT1qeMOxtQU?p=preview