# How to get a URL query next to the "#!" prefix?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to get the URL query next the "#!" prefix, for example:
https://mega.co.nz/#!123abc

```
<?php
$query=$_GET["#!"]; //the example
?>
```

$query: 123abc.

It is possible to read the query using PHP or .htaccess file? How i can get started?

Thanks for reading and for any help! :)

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/940923/5645769

Comment: Also this answer explains better : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2317523/5645769

Comment: Yeah that solved my problem :) As conclusion isn't possible to read the fragment after the hash # using pure PHP, but yes with some helps of JavaScript: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/15/read-the-anchor-part-of-the-url-with-php/

Thanks a lot! I hope won't have problems trying to read the "!" symbol in JavaScript. Regards!

Answer (score -1):

Try this, 
Let your URL:

```
 https://mega.co.nz?query=123abc
```

Then you can get value as below :

```
 <?php
     $query=$_GET["query"]; //the example
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! But I need to use the #! prefix to make the links unredeable for some content stealing bots.

I think this is possible using a some Regex inside the .htaccess, sending the query readable to PHP without changing the visitor URL (in bacckground I guess), but.... I don't know how to get started :S.  Regards! :)