# How to get hash(#) value in query string

Tags: php

I am trying to post # parameter in query string like...

```
www.demo.php?tag=c#
```

Now i am trying to get tag value in another page with

```
$_GET['tag']
```

But i am not getting somehow # value is not coming with $_GET. I can get only "c".

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2317508/3933332

Answer (score 1):

The hash character (`#`) has a special meaning in URLs. It introduces a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). A fragment identifier is usually used to locate a certain position inside the page.

A fragment identifier is handled by the browser, it is removed from the URL when the browser makes the HTTP request to the server.

Being a special character, if you want it to have its literal value you must encode it. The correct way to write the URL in your question is:

```
www.demo.php?tag=c%23
```

When it's written this way, `$_GET['tag']` contains the correct value (`'c#'`).

If you generate such URLs from PHP code (probably by getting the values of `tag` from an external resource like a database) you have to use the PHP function [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to properly encode the values you put in URLs. Or, even better, create an array with all the URL arguments and their values then pass it to [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to generate the URL:

```
$params = array(
   'tag'  => 'c#',
   'page' => 2,
);
$url = 'http://localhost/demo.php?'.http_build_query($params);
```

Comment: Already tried this. its not working...

Comment: Try harder. It works.

Comment: Actually i have changed my url with htaccess for clean url. like http://localhost/demo/tag/c#/

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it very well. You **cannot** put `#` unencoded in an URL, if you want it to be `#` and not something else. The same for `?`, `%`, `/`, `&`, `=` and several other characters. It doesn't matter if you use URL rewriting or not. I clicked on the link you put in your comment. The server replied with *"The requested URL `/demo/tag/c` was not found on this server."*. See? No `#` reaches the server if it is not [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Still not convinced? Search for [tag:c#] on StackOverflow and check the (nice and clean) URL you get.

Comment: Axiac, i have not issue to use url like www.demo.com/tag/c%23/    but when i am trying to get this value of tag on another page using $_GET['tag'], i can only see 'c' not 'c#' or 'c%23'

Comment: Maybe your rewriting rules are the cause. `print_r($_SERVER);` could help you debug the issue