# How to use # (hashtag) in URL variable

Tags: html

I am trying to pass a variable through the URL.

Here is an example URL : http://www.example.com?activeTab=#myProfile

The #myProfile is supposed to be a jQuery selector, but the variable activeTab ends up being equal to nothing. The hashtag ends up cutting off the variable for some reason.

If I were to remove the hashtag, the variable ends up being 'myProfile'. So the issue is certainly the hashtag.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to encode it https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: # in URLs are used for anchors

Comment: Your code is missing a [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin False. I gave an example URL.

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term, in plain text, should be hyperlinked to a search engine on social media networks. It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Please don’t confuse other uses of the hash character with hashtags. What you are talking about is a **URL [Fragment Identifier](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5)**

Comment: @Wyatt — Then you started talking about variables. URLs don't have variables. Presumably you have some programming language involved. That code is doing something with the URL. We can't tell what because your code is missing. You mentioned jQuery, so presumably you are talking about client side JavaScript … but how it gets from the URL to your code I've no idea.

Comment: @Quentin Of course URLs have variables. They follow the question mark, correct?

Comment: @Quentin Oh, I see your confusion. I am using PHP. They are $_GET variables.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042694/how-to-get-hash-value-in-query-string

Answer (score -1):

You write your jquery code to prepend # in the selector and read value from the param. # has meaning in the URL and thus activeTab=nothing and HTML attempts to look for #myProfile anchor locator on the page

Comment: even tho that's correct, it doesn't solve OPs problem

Comment: I already said OP need to read from param and then use param value in jquery code. That's how OP can use params to OP's desired behavior.