# Fetch Current URL not getting ID , class based filters

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to fetch my current page URL, for an if-else statement.

My URL is like this : http://something.com/fetch_url.php#filter=.apples

And my code is :

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'<br/>';
?>
```

It gives me :

/fetch_url.php only, but i need to check for #filter=.apples , in if-else case.
Please guide.

Comment: the hash part of a url is never sent to the web server.

Comment: Try using a correct URL like `http://something.com/fetch_url.php?filter=apples`

Answer (score 1):

Try using a correct URL like http://something.com/fetch_url.php?filter=apples

# part in the URL never approach to a web server, therefore you cannot access it.

And use if statement like this.

```
if($_REQUEST['filter']=='apples'){
   //then perform your action here according to requirements
}else{
   // otherwise provide instruction for the else condition here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `#` part in the URL can never reaches a web server, hence you cannot access it. One workaround that we have been using is to use Javascript to access it via `window.location.hash`, and then do a separate post to the server to obtain this hash, if it's necessary.

Similar question has been asked before: [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)