# PHP $_GET from url with #

Tags: php, get

I have an url like `index.php?c1=#reqid#&c2=#affid#&s2=#s2#&s5=#s5#`
and `$_GET` parameter did not get nothing. please, tell me why?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#` character in a URL indicates the start of the fragment identifier (which is handled client side and never sent to the server).

If you want to include it as data you must encode it as `%23`.

Comment: @jek: Depending on what is generating the URL :)

Comment: Yes true true __smiles again__ :)