# Get parameters from URL with PHP or jQuery/javascript

Tags: php, url

I have a url and its not a string. Its in the browser's address bar

```
http://localhost/sample/?post_id2#access_key=1654040333
```

How can I get `access_key` parameter that is starting with `#`?

I have tried to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` but in vein.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If it's in the url use the superglobal $_GET: $_GET['post_id'];

Comment: The access_key can't because it is interpreted by the browser to scroll to that specific html element by id

Comment: that url is in a string? or that's the url that's running the script you want to extract the data in?

Comment: What about the `access_key` it is starting with `#` can I get it with `$_GET`?

Comment: Marc B no its not a string

Comment: values after # is client side not server-side, see dup post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parsing the url through javascript

```
alert(window.location.hash);
```

Answer (score 2):

> post_id2#access_key=1654040333

`access_key` is not regular query parameter you'd obtain using i.e.`$_GET`. It's webpage anchor reference used (by design by browsers, but nowadays also by JS frameworks etc). You however are not fully lost as there's [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function that can parse this for you. So:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/sample/?post_id2#access_key=1654040333';
var_dump(parse_url($url));
```

would return you the following array:

```
array(5) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["path"]=>
  string(8) "/sample/"
  ["query"]=>
  string(8) "post_id2"
  ["fragment"]=>
  string(21) "access_key=1654040333"
}
```

so your `access_key` will be in `fragment` key, so you may process it further to get the value:

```
$parse_url_result = parse_url($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
if (array_key_exists('fragment', $parse_url_result)) {
   $tmp = explode('=', $parse_url_result['fragment']);
   $access_key = $tmp[1];
}
```

Comment: You have created the `url` in string. How can I make it as string since its in a browser's address bar

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php. Check edited answer too

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parse_url` to get the required results.

```
$url = "http://localhost/sample/?post_id2#access_key=1654040333";
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
```