# How to access url after # in php

Tags: php, url

I am trying to pass some parameters after # in the url like `http://developer.rohitkhatri.com/test.php#embed=sdkhfjshdkfhhjk`, But I don't know how to access it, I tried many solution from the stackoverflow, here are some examples what I've tried:

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` gives me `/test.php` 
`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` gives empty string 
`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` gives empty string

also tried printing the whole `$_SERVER` array but I did not find anything useful.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use query string instead of # ==> http://developer.rohitkhatri.com/test.php?embed=sdkhfjshdkfhhjk

Comment: Part of string after `#` never passed to server unless you create some javascript magik.

Comment: If you really need '#' then you should use JS to make an Ajax call to test.php passing as parameters whatever you have afther the hash

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php                                       $url=parse_url('http://developer.rohitkhatri.com/test.php#embed=sdkhfjshdkfhhjk');
 echo $url["fragment"];
 you get "embed=sdkhfjshdkfhhjk"
 then  u can explode by '='

Comment: Actually I'm trying to pass some parameters with `bit.ly` shortened url, because when I pass query string with `bitly` url, It doesn't provide them on the server side, but when I pass anything after `#`, It's available on the redirected url. Is there any other way of achieving this, I would be thankful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's no way to achieve this, because the part you are trying to access using the php, never goes to the server, what you can do is, just grab the part using the javascript and send it the the server.

Like there can be a middle page, which will redirect to the final url, and while redirecting, It can grab the part after # and send it using ajax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I did :-)

Answer (score -1):

The browser doesn't send anything that comes after the hash(#) to the server because it is resolved within the browser. You can try by mentioned code.

```
$hash = '<script>document.write(document.location.hash)</script>';
echo $hash;

output :

//#embed=sdkhfjshdkfhhjk
```

Comment: How does this help? I'm not getting the value in `$hash` variable.

Comment: It will show "#embed=sdkhfjshdkfhhjk". If you want to get value after '=' sign than you have 'split' or 'explode'

Comment: So you are saying that php variable `$hash` will hold the `#embed= sdkhfjshdkfhhjk` part, right? and then I can use that php variable to load the page, Is this you are trying to say?