# How to escape hash (#) characters in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have something like the following in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^a/(.+)$ index.php?data=$1 [L]
```

Simple enough, and works for most cases, except when I use the following URL:

```
http://example.com/a/hello%23abc
```

I expect this to set the `data` GET variable to `hello#abc`, but instead it breaks. I assume that it breaks because Apache "unescapes" the characters, making the url the following:

```
index.php?data=hello#abc
```

Which is probably why it's setting the `data` GET variable to `hello`.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: That part is called "fragment" and you can get it in this way:

$url=parse_url("http://domain.com/site/gallery/1#photo45 ");
echo $url["fragment"]; //This variable contains the fragment

use this example on http://stackoverflow.com/a/2317518/4817575

Comment: @JatinderKaur I know, but I don't want to do that - I want the URL to be rewritten to `index.php?data=hello%23abc`

Comment: use [L,R] to see what URL is really rewritten to, `abc` will probably be there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the **[B]** flag should help in your case(*available in Apache 2.2*)

> The [B] flag instructs *RewriteRule* to escape non-alphanumeric
>   characters before applying the transformation.

```
RewriteRule ^a/(.+)$ index.php?data=$1 [L,B]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: Ah yes, exactly what I was searching for. Thanks!