# Can I $_GET the last 5 letters of the url?

Tags: php, post, get

Okay so. I'm planning a minimal pastebin, for personal use. What I want is the URL to be:

> http://xmpl.com/#paste/xY78r # 5 last chars being randomly generated

Thing is, I do not know how to get the last 5 characters. I would know how to get them if the URL was

> http://xmpl.com/#paste?x=xY78r

, by simply using:

```
$x = $_GET['x'];
```

So question: Can I make the URL like: `http://xmpl.com/#paste/xY78r` and get the last five characters similar to the `$_GET` example above (to make a MySQL request for that character combination), without creating a folder on my server called `xY78r`?

Horribly explained, sorry, I tried. Not looking for a ready solution, just a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: no. `#` are not sent to the server. you'd need JS to intercept the click, parse the `#` out of the url, and convert it into a regular `script.php?x=xY78r` url

Comment: @MarcB Alright, thanks Marc. I might just have to do this the correct way

Comment: You could use a RewriteRule in your .htaccess and then just use $_GET in PHP as you were planning to

Comment: I wouldn't use random characters since then the only way to see if it exists or not is to do multiple DB queries until you find one that is not taken yet. I would instead recommend http://hashids.org/php/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)