# Adding a hashtag to a URL in Laravel 4

Tags: php, url, laravel-4, encode, router

How can I add a hashtag (`#`) to a URL in Laravel? I want something like this:

```
domain.com/stack/#/x/y
```

How can I use it in Laravel 4 routes?

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php). The browser does not send the hash portion of the URL (anything that comes after the first # character) to the server so it is not possible to create a route on the server side that includes one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)