# How to get values of URL parameters in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm facing difficulty in fetching URL parameters from redirect URL of Fitbit I'm here trying to integrate Fitbit without using socialite or any other package.

I have the following URL:

```
http://localhost/abc/public/portal/fitbit/fitbitIntegration#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1WjVLUzUiLCJhdWQiOiIyMjhMNjUiLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iLCJzY29wZXMiOiJ3aHIgd251dCB3cHJvIHdzbGUgd3dlaSB3c29jIHdzZXQgd2FjdCB3bG9jIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1NDU5MTM2LCJpYXQiOjE1MDQ4NzE1MjF9.iQ9nxbzmvar2DlG_848b3MTefq7q0wxyXByTb1Bb2o4&user_id=5Z5KS5&scope=sleep+settings+nutrition+activity+social+heartrate+profile+weight+location&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=587615
```

All I want to fetch all the information after the `#` like I want to get  `user_id` here

I have tried this to accomplish

```
public function fitbitIntegration(Request $request)
{
    try{
        $authId = Auth::user()->id;

        $fitbit = new FitbitMaster();
        $fitbit->user_id = $authId;
        $fitbit->fitbit_client_id = $request->user_id;
        $fitbit->save();
        flash('Connected', 'success');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    catch (QueryException $exception)
    {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('fitbitIntegration', 'BackEnd\fitbit@fitbitIntegration');
```

But I'm not getting the `user_id` here which got me Integrity constraint error

How to get `user_id` here in my case?

Comment: There are `#` in your url, thats why you are not getting url parameters

Comment: yes but I can't change that '#' because it's third party they have such url scheme now how could I able to get this id?

Comment: you can use js to get the url parameters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby See this answer for more explanation on how this is not possible on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Demo_Link:** http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hdcu-3axu

Store Your Dynamic Url in any variable, in your controller and Do Like This.

```
<?php

//store  your dynamic url in any variable

    $url = "http://localhost/abc/public/portal/fitbit/fitbitIntegration#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1WjVLUzUiLCJhdWQiOiIyMjhMNjUiLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iLCJzY29wZXMiOiJ3aHIgd251dCB3cHJvIHdzbGUgd3dlaSB3c29jIHdzZXQgd2FjdCB3bG9jIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1NDU5MTM2LCJpYXQiOjE1MDQ4NzE1MjF9.iQ9nxbzmvar2DlG_848b3MTefq7q0wxyXByTb1Bb2o4&user_id=5Z5KS5&scope=sleep+settings+nutrition+activity+social+heartrate+profile+weight+location&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=587615";


    $access_token = substr($url, strpos($url, "#") + 1);    

    echo $access_token; // get the string of acess token with parametes

?>
```

---

> ### UPDATED

**NOTE:** fragment part of url after the `#` It's never sent to the server side, So.. its not possible to get the that using any `$_SERVER[..]` in php but we can read it. So Now we can use `JAVA SCRIPT MAGIC` do this:

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<?php 

//Here you Can See save.php page inside an $url where its redirect with your access_token after clicking on `Click Here` link (in your case its redirect routes `fitbitIntegration` as you mentioned ). So i try to create the situation as your routes after its redirect with token, Fine !! 

$url = "http://localhost/save.php/fitbitIntegration#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1WjVLUzUiLCJhdWQiOiIyMjhMNjUiLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iLCJzY29wZXMiOiJ3aHIgd251dCB3cHJvIHdzbGUgd3dlaSB3c29jIHdzZXQgd2FjdCB3bG9jIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1NDU5MTM2LCJpYXQiOjE1MDQ4NzE1MjF9.iQ9nxbzmvar2DlG_848b3MTefq7q0wxyXByTb1Bb2o4&user_id=5Z5KS5&scope=sleep+settings+nutrition+activity+social+heartrate+profile+weight+location&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=587615";

?>

<a  target="_blank" href="<?php echo $url; ?>"> Click Here </a>

<?php
echo '<br><br><br>';
?>


<!-- Now after redirect you have to use an javascript inside controller or inside an routes directly to aceess the url an getting an access_token, here i try to store inside the cookies of using js and retrieve it using php and echo -->

<?php

echo "<script language='javascript'>

token = window.location.hash.split('#')

    document.cookie='access_token='+token[1];
    document.cookie='token[1]';
    alert(token[1]);
    document.cookie='token[1]';

    if (token[1] != '') {
        //window.location.reload()
        //location.reload(true);
}
else{

//document.cookie='token[1]'; 

}

</script>";

//token_name=$_COOKIE['access_token'];

// Here We get the  access token inside the $_COOKIE['access_token'];  

if(isset($_COOKIE['access_token'])){

    echo $_COOKIE['access_token'];
}

?>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: bhai mere controller function mein implement kr de isko kaise krna hai

Comment: problem lies here how to get url value in `$url`

Comment: I think You can get the URL from the routes in Laravel and then you can use/store it inside your controller.

Comment: I don't have that url in route it is a third party url

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid .. Ok give me some time :)

Comment: Mm.. yeah sure :)

Comment: Happy to Help Bhai :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value after the hash mark or anchor as shown in a user's browser: This isn't possible with `"standard"` HTTP as this value is never sent to the server (hence it won't be available in `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` or similar predefined variables). You would need some sort of `JavaScript` magic on the client side, e.g. to include this value as a POST parameter.

That part is called "fragment". If you have any **static url** then you can get it in this way:

```
$url=parse_url("http://localhost/abc/public/portal/fitbit/fitbitIntegration#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1WjVLUzUiLCJhdWQiOiIyMjhMNjUiLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iLCJzY29wZXMiOiJ3aHIgd251dCB3cHJvIHdzbGUgd3dlaSB3c29jIHdzZXQgd2FjdCB3bG9jIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1NDU5MTM2LCJpYXQiOjE1MDQ4NzE1MjF9.iQ9nxbzmvar2DlG_848b3MTefq7q0wxyXByTb1Bb2o4&user_id=5Z5KS5&scope=sleep+settings+nutrition+activity+social+heartrate+profile+weight+location&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=587615");
echo $url["fragment"]; //This variable contains the fragment
```

Comment: how could I achieve this in controller any illustration?

Comment: i don't think it is possible in controller methods using php

Comment: hey that link is dynamic I need a I dynamic solution here bro :)

Comment: yeah, that whay i mentioned that in my answer

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR  At least Mention the Link of Copied ANS ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php

Answer (score 0):

you can define a route like `fitbitIntegration/{param}` and in your function fitbitIntegration, you add param like fitbitIntegration ( Request $req, $param); then you can use regex on your params to get want you want

Comment: not getting as parameter got not Not Found Exception

Comment: share your web or api file