# How to set og:url to jquery gallery slides?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, facebook

Hey good people of the internet.

I'd like to set the meta og:url to the slides in my jquery gallery. 

I'm using lightGallery on a Wordpress site.

When using facebook object debugger my url (slide) `site/page#lg=1&slide=0` becomes `site/page`.

site/page is listed as Canonical URL in the object debugger - I would like this to be the gallery slide, `site/page#lg=1&slide=0`.

So how can I set the og:url to the slides and then hopefully have that full url to be the canonical url?

It has been done here, I think... https://postimg.org/image/7472hl0g7f/

There's a huge high five at stakes here :)

Comment: url fragments are ignored by the debugger

Comment: @luschn Really appreciate your answer. 
But there must be a way to set the fragment as og:url.
It's done here: https://postimg.org/image/7472hl0g7f/
Or am I completely off mark? :)

Comment: can you share one of your own urls?

Comment: i hope you don´t set the tags dynamically, because facebook ignores javascript ;)

Comment: @luschn sure. http://thunder-power.dk/album/guldtuben#lg=1&slide=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test URL: http://thunder-power.dk/album/guldtuben#lg=1&slide=0

The OG tag of that URL:

`<meta property="og:url" content="http://thunder-power.dk/album/guldtuben" />`

The fragment is missing in the `og:url`, as you can see. JavaScript will be ignored, you have to set the correct `og:url` server side.

Information about how to get the fragment with PHP: [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot!
I can't see how I would be able to get the right fragment for the right slide, server-side. Gotta get to typing and trying out then.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because your plugin using 'href' instead of 'data-src' attributes.
Check this link : https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/issues/103

**EDIT :**

Manually add the data-src before executing the lightGallery plugin:

```
$("article section.body figure").each(function() {
    var image = $(this).find('img'),
        link = $(this).find('a');

    image.attr('data-src', link.attr('href'));

    link.lightGallery();
});
```

Comment: @Paul Thanks. I'm using data-attributes

Answer (score 0):

I think You are setting dynamically meta data using Jquery/js. For meta property set content attribute like:  `<meta property="og:url" content="https://csample.com">`

It is not possible for facebook crawler to execute Jquery to get updated meta data for dynamic state parameters of url like #lg=1&slide=0. FB object debugger will show nil for #lg=1&slide=0 and gives meta response only for site/page , until you does not make static page page for each #lg=1&slide=0 or make prerendered html reference for crawler.

Comment: Thanks for replying :)