# Is there a generic URL builder/manipulator in Drupal/Symfony?

Tags: symfony, drupal-8

How to build and/or modify generic URLs on Drupal/Symfony?

For example, having at the input an URL like: `http://some.url/with?param1=value1#fragment` I would like to be able to manipulate any parts of the url including:

- cut off the query (search) part
- add more query parameters
- change the path part
- replace domain
- add/change fragment
- etc

I couldn't find anything appropriate in Drupal or Symfony.

Comment: This should be possible with Symfony's request and the router component

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 there is [`lib/Drupal/Core/Url.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x) class which provide some methods to get/set parameters

**Availables methods to setting the route parameters:**

```
setRouteParameters($parameters)
setRouteParameter($key, $value)
```

**Availables methods to set the route options:**

```
setOptions($options)
setOption($name, $value)
```

**How to use the setParameter method:**

```
/**
* @var Drupal\Core\Url $url
*/
$url->setRouteParameter('arg_0', $arg0);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Symfony 3.3 you can use `Request::create($url)`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$url = 'http://some.url/with?param1=value1#fragment'
$req = Request::create($url)
```

Then you can call

```
$req->getQueryString() // param1=value1
$req->getHost() // some.url
$req->getSchemeAndHttpHost() // http://some.url
$req->getBaseUrl() // /with
```

Ref http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

I don't think this class provides any setter for host/param/path so you can do the following:

```
str_replace($req->getHost(), 'new-host.com', $url) // change host
```

About the hash fragment `#fragment`, it doesn't seem to be available on server-side (see [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)).