# Access token Print from an URL

Tags: php

I am trying to grab #access_token from a URL, it doesn't print anything

My url is like the following `test.php#access_token=2f6b037435a6fc614ff5cab8a188dc70c4953f78%27`

My PHP code:

```
echo $_GET['#access_token']
```

I tried the following as well

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url=parse_url($url);
echo $url["fragment"]; //This variable contains the fragment
```

Comment: That's not what get parameters looks like... They'd be more like `test.php?access_token=2f6b037435a6fc614ff5cab8a188dc70c4953f78%27`. Notice the `?` instead of `#`

Comment: It needs to be a question mark not a `#`  -- IE `test.php?access_token=2f6b037435a6fc614ff5cab8a188dc70c4953f78%27`  --- Next, remove the `#` from the `_GET` --  IE `$_GET['access_token']`

Comment: there is no question mark after.php its #, its a webservice that returns that url

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2317508/3578036

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)

Comment: ^ a.k.a it can't be done - the URL fragment is never sent to the server

Comment: *"its a webservice that returns that url"* ... if you're connecting to a web service, then that URL isn't a header response surely?

Comment: What exactly was wrong with your `parse_url()` attempt?  If you actually are getting (somehow) a URL that contains a hash-delimited fragment, then using `parse_url()` should be able to grab that fragment just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue using Javascript, so grab the # from the URL, append that to the PHP page, redirect

```
   <script language="javascript">

    var strURL=(window.location.hash.substr(1));
     window.location.href = 'test-new.php?access_token ='
                           + strURL;
    </script>
```