# How to parse url parametrs having '#' in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal

I have a url like: **abc.com/cde#token=somevale**

How do I capture the **token** value from Drupal 8 routing system.

It was easy when the url was like **abc.com/cde?token=somevale** , the token parameter can easily be retrieved via \Drupal::request->query->get('token').

But how to capture something after # ??

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: `#foo` is not something you can access in php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)