# How to use $_GET when there is &038; at place of & in url

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding

I have wordpress template in which URL is generating in for of xyz.com/?pickup_location=662#038;pickup_date=2018%2F08%2F08&return_date=2018%2F08%2F10
you can see there & at a place of & so when I trying to get value by $_GET['pickup_date'] it showing blank.

I used $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  to get complete URL but it's also not giving me complete URL

it's look like there is use of esc_url() wordpress function.
 if anyone can help me to get this complete url as a string it can also work for me I could split a string with a parameter name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `#`.

Everything that comes after the `#` is only accessible by the client and not the server.

If you need a `#` in your URL like that you need to URL encode it:

```
urlencode('#'); // %23
```

In your case that will be something like this:

```
$url = "xyz.com/?pickup_location=" . urlencode("662#038;") . "pickup_date=2018%2F08%2F08&return_date=2018%2F08%2F10";
```

Comment: ?pickup_location=662#038;pickup_date=2018%2F08%2F08 & #038;return_date=2018%2F08%2F10 complete url is this do you have any suggestion to get this complete url?