# Javascript location hash into php variable

Tags: javascript, php

Am trying to get the current URL that contains a hash e.g (http://www.example.com/index.php#folder23242%FNew). Anything after the hash the variable must store it in PHP variable. I have added the script but the PHP does not recognize the Javascript variable value and prints no value.
I need it to take the Javascript variable so it can execute my php script.

```
echo '<script>
var url = ""; 
url = location.hash;
url = decodeURI(url);
document.cookie="currenturl=url";
</script>';
$url = "";
$url = $_COOKIE["currenturl"];
$arr = explode('/', $url);
$url = end($arr);

echo "<script>alert('".$url."')</script>";
```

Comment: PHP is Server Side and JS is client side. JS will always execute (on client side) after PHP(on server side). How are you expecting this to work.

Comment: PHP does not get URL that values that contain a # even if you USE "REQUEST URI" etc hence the use of Javascript. Unless there is a to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

**Impossible** to get hash from current url.

`$_SERVER['REQUET_URI']` only contains path and query string.

The browser does not send the fragment to the server.

> Answer is 'Standard methods will not help you."

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in your cookie with `document.cookie="currenturl=location.toString()";`

Then access it from your php code,

```
$url = $_COOKIE["currenturl"];
echo parse_url($url)["fragment"];
```

---

**Example:**

```
php > print_r(parse_url("https://example.com/#folder"));
Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => example.com
    [path] => /
    [fragment] => folder
)
```