# Laravel - Get parameter that starts with '#'

Tags: php, laravel

Im creating an autocomplete feature that my users can search for strings that starts with '#' but Im getting the following behaviour:

**Controller**

```
public function autocomplete(Request $request, TermoBuscaService $service)
{
    dd($request->input('term'));
}
```

**Input**

It Works

`[GET] /autocomplete?term=music`

**Output**

`music`

**Input**

Doesnt works

`[GET] /autocomplete?term=#music`

**Output**

`null`

Does laravel have some sort of sanitize that removes hashtags?

Comment: The hash part is never sent to back-end. Maybe first URL encode your term?

Comment: Oh. I see now. Thanks Justinas!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)