# how to get last part of url in $variable

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i am working on a wordpress website, and i am little stuck into one sitautation,

i want to store the last part of url in $variable. here below is my URL

```
https://jobifyinc.com/newsite/my-profile/#tab2
```

i want to store #tab2 in $variable

i tried the following code but it only returns me the  my-profile as a last part

```
   global $post;
   $post_slug = $post->post_name;
```

anyother best and alternative option?

Comment: use `explode` to break the string into array and then use `end` to get the last art of array

Comment: `$url = "https://jobifyinc.com/newsite/my-profile/#tab2";
$arr = explode("/",$url);
print_r(end($arr));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)

Comment: @urfusion thats fine you manually add url in $url, but i dynamically need that url in $variable, do you have another answer

Comment: Do you want the "last part of the URL" as per your question title, or do you really mean that you want to get the hash part of the URL if there is one, and nothing otherwise?