# Jump to a page section from URL id in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am working for a QA forum. I have a question and searched for that but did not find any better solution.
In the login system, I am getting redirect_to URL like-

```
http://localhost:8081/qa/506/how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php#ans123
```

This is what I will use after login.  I know,  I can use
`<a name="ans123"></a>` to jump section or by id .

1. I am Getting value from the URL like -

   login.php?redirect_to=http://localhost:8081/qa/506/how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php#ans123

   redirect_to=$_GET['redirect_to'];

but it gives me only `http://localhost:8081/qa/506/how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php`

not

```
http://localhost:8081/qa/506/how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php#ans123
```

with #ans123 .

I want to jump the user to textarea after login on to the question page.

I have a textarea in then bottom with name="textarea"

```html
<a name="ans123"> </a>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <textarea name="anscontent" required></textarea>
  <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace("anscontent", {
      height: 300,
      filebrowserUploadUrl: "upload.php",
    });
  </script>

  <button name="answer_submit">Post your Answer</button>
</form>
```

One more thing, I have seen a method like

```
 http://localhost:8081/qa/506/how-to-connect-the-html-page-to-the-mysql-database-using-php?state=ans-890 .
```

If I open this URL it opens textarea.

1. How can I jump to the Textarea box area after login (Bottom HTML text editor)
2. How can I edit the answer. if the user clicks on the edit button or link then jump to textbox and edit data. After the edit submitted jump to the updated answer.

Comment: [Please do better research next time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)

Comment: In the redirect_to you should urlencode the # to %23 so that the php script can see it and redirect the user properly after login.