# Have PHP figure out the HTML anchor name a page was loaded with

Tags: php

I'm working on a functionality that requires the php script to know the html anchor name a page has been loaded with. I'm finding such of dearth of information on the topic I'm not even sure if I'm using the right nomenclature.

Basically I would have someone landing on a page using an internal anchor. Something like
`www.mypage.com/index.php#my_place_in_page` or `www.mypage.com/index.php?param=42#my_place_in_page`.
In this case my goal would be to get `my_place_in_page` into my script somehow.

I've gone through the whole list of things that $_SERVER can get me, and it doesn't seem to be there. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will return `www.mypage.com/index.php` or `www.mypage.com/index.php?param=42`, but always cuts off after the hash.

Is there any way to get the anchor name? Or is the reason I can't find any references to this because it's just not something that php does.

Thanks for help or insight that anyone can offer.

Comment: Add the anchor name as a CGI parameter on the page with the link?

Comment: While the value isn't available to PHP, JavaScript can grab it and send it to the server via an AJAX request. More conversation on the topic can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317523/2585216