# Browser removing "#" on link open

Tags: html

I currently set this link

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://alceawisteria.byethost7.com/PHP/0demo/2023-03-25-BoxNet/rolling.php#download?i=1"><font size="+9">(↓)</font></a>
```

However there are times when the "#download part is simply removed, why ?

Comment: Perhaps that other site is doing a redirect

Comment: But not always. Sometimes it leaves the "#download", other times it straight up removes it . Firefox, Chrome n Opera all have that phenomenon

Comment: PHP usually doesn't get the hash part of an URL (it's intra-browser)

Comment: It works sometimes tho... (mostly when I load the page the second time)

Comment: Depends on browser, see [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url)

Comment: I do not want the fragment perse, I just need it to remain, as the final script in the page reacts to it...

Comment: Sometimes browser decides if # still remains on the url or not. If so, why not to use the hastag code so the link has a *fixed* # on the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However there are times when the "#download part is simply removed, why ?

If you inspect the element of the [HTML](http://alceawisteria.byethost7.com/PHP/0demo/2023-03-25-BoxNet/rolling.php), you can find this:

```html
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (location.href.indexOf("#download") != -1) {
    //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    document.getElementById('linky').click()

  }
</script>
...
```

That script runs: if `#download` exists, button `#linky` will be clicked.

```html
...
<a id="linky"
  onclick="this.href='data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)"
  href="#" download="rollingyourpage.html" style="color:transparent">
  <font size="+5">Download</font>
</a>
...
```

When button `#linky` is clicked, page will redirect to `base64` link format with String `document.documentElement.outerHTML`. Hope that helps.