# telegram bot web app receives data with GET method #tgWebAppData php

Tags: php, get, telegram-bot

This data does not exist in  `$_SERVER`

example url wep app request

```
https://example.com/index.php#tgWebAppData=query_id=AAEb3dV3AgAAABvd1Xds7_Fh&user=%7B%22id%22%3A633121272%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22My%20Name%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22My_username%22%2C%22language_code%22%3A%22uz%22%2C%22is_premium%22%3Atrue%2C%22allows_write_to_pm%22%3Atrue%7D&auth_date=1704877606&hash=7b0246bd8f3d7714057bffefb6bdd8adf2b95916e36632d352cd68e525838510
```

I checked `$_SERVER` and there was no information about it. How do I receive such `$_GET` data?
or do I have to rework it by writing codes in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Everything after (and including) the `#` is treated by the browser as an anchor in the page it is requesting. The anchor isn't sent to the server. I suspect you have the wrong format for the query string.

Comment: `#` is not a GET request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned in comments, the part of a URL following a `#` is the "fragment" or "anchor", historically used to move the viewport within a page and without talking to the server and recently often to hold more complex clientside state. It's not sent as part of an HTTP request.

Query strings are `key=value` pairs following a `?` and separated by `&`, and *are* sent to the server. Given your example, that `#` should probably be a `?`.

---

You can learn about the parts of a URL, which is a kind of URI, from Wikipedia's [exhaustive page on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) or from [Mozilla's web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL).

Here's Mozilla's fancy little explanation by image:
[image]

Comment: but this part ```#tgWebAppData=query_id=AAEb3dV3AgAAABvd1Xds7_Fh&user=%7B%22id%22%3A633121272%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22My%20Name%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22%22%2C% 22username%22%3A%22My_username%22%2C%22language_code%22%3A%22uz%22%2C%22is_premium%22%3Atrue%2C%22allows_write_to_pm%22%3Atrue%7D&auth_date=1704877606&hash=7b0246bd8f3d7714057bffefb6bdd8 adf2b95916e36632d352cd68e525838510``` in my telegram application is sending to my website can i just reprocess it via javascript and sending it to my server?

Comment: Since that appears to be a (nearly) valid and escaped query string besides its incorrect signifier, you could certainly send it like `fetch("my.endpoint/whatever?" + that_string.slice(1))` - or however else you prefer. The `tgWebAppData=` section at the start may trip you up. If you're using a library and/or tutorial and it has asked you to format the data this way, you may need to go off its rails a little to achieve what you actually want.