# Value with # in query string does not receive full data

Tags: php

I have one url with one code.
http://www.example.com/exam.php?id=rteter#443545

Now when I click this URL, the value of the id is **rteter**, means it returns me only portion of code before #.

I have not sent the link with urlencode so please do not give that solutions. Links are already sent, is they any way by which I can get the full value in my php code?

Martha

Answer (score 0):

The `#` character indicates the start of the fragment identifier and is handled client side. You need to represent it as `%23` if you want it sent to the server.

If you are generating query string parameters programatically in PHP, use the [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) function.

Comment: ya, but link is already sent without this, so cant do anything now. Anything i can do on page where i receive this code?

Comment: Find the URL in the markup with JavaScript and rewrite it. The terms "stable door" and "already bolted" come to mind though.

Comment: Oh. I'm guessing you might mean "sent in an email" or something. Look to see if there is a `location.hash` in JS, and then redirect.

Comment: David link is already sent so user will just click the link. cant do anything now

Comment: *When they visit /exam.php?id=rteter*  look to see if there is a `location.hash` in JS, and then redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url) on stackoverflow:
[Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

It might cover your question.

Answer (score 0):

use url quote

```
http://www.example.com/exam.php?id='rteter%23443545'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: then use parse_url (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the fragment part and join it with the id parameter

Comment: ps: your idea is wrong actually. take a look at these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181290/php-zend-framework-how-to-get-request-uri-fragment-from-request-object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url